# Stop prograpagation in selectize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

I've spend an hour trying to make this [jsfiddle splendid selectize modification](http://jsfiddle.net/n7cynj34/) to stop close (stopPropagation) on option selection , but I am now feeling helpless. Do I have to use some of selectize option for this ? I've read the [doc](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) through, but found nothing relevant. The only relevant option seems to be closeAfterSelect, but its default value is false :(
Any ideas ?

```
$('.dropdown').each(function() {
    $_self = $(this);
    $_self.find('select')
        .selectize({ plugins: ['component'], maxItems: 1, closeAfterSelect:false })
        .on('change', function() {
            console.log('Changed value to:', $(this).val() )
            $_self.find('span.value').text( $(this).val() )
            if ($(this).val()) {
                $_self.removeClass('open');
            }
        });
    $_self.find('select').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
    $_self.find('.dropdown-menu').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); });
     $_self.find('.dropdown').on('click', function(e) { e.stopPropagation(); })
});
```

Once again to clarify - I want the drop down to close only when I press the caret. If I choose any option, I want it to stay open. As you may notice, I've added the stopPropagation method on each class and element possible and yet can't get it work as expected

Comment: A Proof of Concept in a jsbin/jsfiddle would help A LOT....

Comment: @MattDiMu thats what his splendid selctize link is

Comment: It seems that its the dropdown thats the issue and not selectize

Comment: Well, the link is provided. I need to fix it there

Comment: @Craicerjack true, didn't see the link. A possible solution should be below as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the e.stopPropagation() is executed too early and therefore won't do anything. But you may `return false` the on-change-event:

http://jsfiddle.net/MattDiMu/ozmqek7b/1/

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks much for that